# Aligning vertical axes in a tri-axes graph

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a line graph that is tracking 2 different values in correlation with time. It basically looks like this
[image: Line Graph]

How do I change the scaling of each of the two in order for the two `0` values align? Right now the `0` value of the left Axes is not at the same place as the `0` value of the right axes. Is it even possible?

I am using Microsoft excel online to generate this graph.
The values are basically 2 separate columns, and each line represents a moment in time (month) for both set of values.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I updated it with more info

Comment: I might provide the file itself, or an example of similar, for analysis.

Comment: Do you have a sample about the data source?

Comment: @Lee
It's just 3 columns of data, I'm not sure what exactly is required. I cannot really provide the file due to the contents of it. One column is end of month data, the other one is a value, and the other one is a percentage calculated value.

Comment: @Lee I meant "end of month date" instead of "data"

Comment: Format each axis and adjust the minimum and maximum bounds so the zeros fall on the same line

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yeah, I was playing around yesterday and noticed that it was THAT simple after all